# Programming Windows Compiler Link Error - unresolved external

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, linker

I am new to Windows Programming.

I created a win32 console project (without preCompiled header) with VS2005. And the code as below.

```
// HelloWin.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int _tmain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HelloWin");
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASS    wndclass;

    wndclass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName  = szAppName;

    if(!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This Program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;

    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,                  // window class name
                        TEXT("The Hello Program"),  // window caption
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x size
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y size
                        NULL,                       // parent window handle
                        NULL,                       // window menu handle
                        hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                        NULL);                      // creation parameters

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC         hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT        rect;

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        PlaySound(TEXT("hellowin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello Windows XP"), -1, &rect, 
                 DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }   
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And now there is two Link Errors as this, Could anybody help me to fix this errors.

Does it caused by there is no `hellowin.wav` file in my local harddisk? If it does. What directory can I place a simular WAV file to?

Thanks.

> 1>Linking... 1>HelloWin.obj :
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol **imp__PlaySoundW@12 referenced in function "long __stdcall
>   WndProc(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)"
>   (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
>   1>D:\learning\windows\ProgrammingWindows(5thEdition)\HelloWin\Debug\HelloWin.exe
>   :
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 1>Build log was saved at
>
> "file://d:\learning\windows\ProgrammingWindows(5thEdition)\HelloWin\HelloWin\Debug\BuildLog> .htm"
>   1>HelloWin - 2 error(s), 1 warning(s)
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here. Firstly you say that your application is a console app. If it is, then you are using the wrong main. Your subsystem is probably WINDOWS in which case your main should be this instead:

```
int CALLBACK _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
```

You also say you're not using precompiled headers but you have an include for `stdafx.h`. Your problems can be fixed by changing your main and also changing your includes to look like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
```

This allows the linker to look for the library file we tell it to. I also got rid of your precompiled header and replaced it with `tchar.h` since that is your only other dependency so far.

The fact `hellowin.wav` is not present at compilation time is irrelevant. The program only looks for it at runtime.

Comment: I realized my problems. And I recreated an Empty Win32 porject. And added a empty 'helloWin.c' file. And this time, I used your main function and header files. It works quite well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tested and found that `CALLBACK` in  `int CALLBACK _tWinMain()` can be ignored. Could you give me more information at the keyword of `CALLBACK`? Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx - This explains it better than I could. Long story short, don't take it out.